# VBA: IE Automation: Retrieving URL from Open IE Window; Runtime Error 438

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I have checked out a few useful threads on how to check for the title of an internet explorer window to retrieve the URL.
I have this:

```
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    For Each wd In objShell.Windows

        If InStr(wd.document.Title, "College") = 1 Then
           Exit For
        End If
    Next wd

    Worksheets("BTS").Cells(2, 2).Value = wd.LocationURL
```

But I keep getting "Runtime Error 438: Object Doesn't Support Property or Method" on the If InStr line. I cannot figure out why it is throwing this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not every Shell window is an instance of IE, so you need to check the Type before trying to access the hosted Document object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
Dim objShell, sTitle, wd 

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each wd In objShell.Windows
    sTitle = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    sTitle = wd.document.Title
    On Error Goto 0
    If InStr(sTitle, "College") = 1 Then
       Exit For
    End If
Next wd

Worksheets("BTS").Cells(2, 2).Value = wd.LocationURL
```